# How do I Regex match file names in bash? i.e. tail -f /var/log/(syslog|mail.log)

Tags: bash, regular-expression

I've been typing commands like the (the long way) for my whole life.

```
tail -f /var/log/syslog /var/log/mail.log /var/log/mail.err
```

This is probably a really basic question, but I had a hard time finding the answer.

Is there a regex way to match multiple files in the folder without retyping the location each time?

This saves me a few keystrokes, but not many

```
export LOGDIR=/var/log
tail -f $LOGDIR/syslog $LOGDIR/mail.log $LOGDIR/mail.err
```

And sometimes I want multiple locations... I want to figure out something like this:

```
tail -f /var/log/(mail*|syslog|nginx/*)
```

(but actually have it work)

Comment: Note those are not regular expressions, but shell patterns.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use brace-expansion.

```
tail -f /var/log/{mail*,syslog,nginx/*}
```

Example:

```
$ tree
├── mail.err
├── mail.log
├── nginx
│   ├── a
│   ├── b
│   └── c
├── notthis
└── syslog
$ echo {mail*,syslog,nginx/*}
mail.err mail.log syslog nginx/a nginx/b nginx/c
```

Answer (score 2):

In `bash`:

```
shopt -s extglob ## enable extend-glob if not enabled; default is "on"
tail -f /var/log/+(syslog|mail.+(log|err))
```

or apparently:

```
tail -f /var/log/+(syslog|mail*)
```

Please note that these are filename globing and applicable only for the files, so you should not expect to have expansion on the *path* like in `nginx/*` you said; instead you can prefer to use brace-expansion based solution and answer given by [Quasímodo](/a/620855/72456) or just explicitly separate that as another parameter to the command:

```
tail -f /var/log/+(syslog|mail*) /var/log/nginx/*
```

Comment: I couldn't make this work with subdirectories, I tried `echo +(syslog|mail.+(log|err)|nginx/*)`. Did I miss something or is it not possible?

Comment: @Quasímodo not possible, that's for filename globing not the path

Answer (score 0):

Doing `tail -f file1 file2` will follow `file1` until "done" (never) before it gets to `file2`. However, `multitail` handles multiple files simultaneously. `sudo apt install multitail;man multitail`.

Comment: I've always used Ubuntu and I get updates from each file as it comes in. For real-time monitoring, this isn't an issue.